# Difference between String.prototype.includes/contains in ES6? What about .has?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, ecmascript-6

I was wondering which of these methods will become the standard. From what I've seen is that both methods yield similar results, yet I'm not sure why there is two versions/aliases. Is there a difference among them? Also, why did ES6 use `.has` when it could've used `.contains` or `.includes` to serve multiple purposes under one name.

I am aware `.has` isn't used on strings.

Support from my tests:

```
        | Contains      Includes
Chrome  | No            Yes
Firefox | Yes           Yes
NodeJS  | Yes           No
```

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains) section in MDN. Also, which version of Node.js you are using?

Comment: `Node v0.12.0` with `--harmony` flag and `"use strict"`. From reading this page, it looks like firefox is going to remove `contains`, and NodeJS is going to be a dumbass that likes to be special. However... It would be nice if `.has` fell under a different name.

Comment: Node.js doesn't have anything to do with this. It just uses v8 to support the JavaScript language. As Node v0.12.0 uses a very old version of v8 (3.28.73), I would recommend you to update.

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.includes returns a boolean.

Array.prototype.indexOf returns a number.

Array.prototype.contains is no native JS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they wanted to dodge some compatibility problems.  I am not sure what those are, but I would guess at the time Firefox and NodeJS had implementations that were different enough that they needed to avoid them.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-Array.prototype.includes/commit/4b6b9534582cb7991daea3980c26a34af0e76c6c